# jsch Auth Fail while connecting to a unix box

Tags: java, jsch

I am trying to read a simple file from a path in my UAT server. Testing from my local - I keep getting the JschException:Auth fail. The code I am using as below:

```
 java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();

        String passwd = "----";
        session.setPassword(passwd);
        Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
```

I tried to add the key to the known_hosts of my local drive, but it does not change anything. The error I get is as below:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:473)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:145)
at gundam.uatchecker.impl.Shell.main(Shell.java:91)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Some help would be much appreciated.
Additionally, I tried to add known hosts like below:

```
ssh-keyscan remote_server > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Also other posts - none seem to work here.
Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you have to specify your password before you connect?

Comment: Tried specifying that as well - unfortunately no use.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working :-

```
    JSch jsch = new JSch();

    String path = "PATH TO PRIVATE KEY"; 


    jsch.addIdentity(path);

    jsch.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

    Session session = jsch.getSession(userName, ipToConnect, portToConnect);
    session.connect();

    Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");

    ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("COMMAND TO FIRE");

    channel.setInputStream(null);

    ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);

    InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();

    channel.connect();

    //Read Response Here 

    channel.disconnect();
    session.disconnect();
```